# When and Why I should Explicitly throw an Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm just trying to make my understanding of Exception mechanism more clear.
If something goes wrong when an app is executed, the runtime automatically throws an appropriate exception. If it is so, then **why I should sometimes make some check and explicitly throw a specific exception?**
How to identify such cases (when an exception should be explicitly thrown in code)?

I don't put any example here on purpose, because I'd like to get a general understanding of the throwing exceptions approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the general approach should be [**Fail Fast**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) - you want to identify and handle invalid program conditions as soon as possible, this would mean not just when a particular input is needed within your program logic but as soon as you "receive" this input (which could be way earlier in time and/or lines of codes).

For i.e. public methods that means validating an input first, and if appropriate throw an exception if the input violates what your method expects.

Comment: What if I have a functions that saves a file. So on IO error it will raise an error. But what if i save Temporary file and fail on that, it's not crutial to my app, but some Data file obviously yes. Is it better to make exceptions cascade architecture and at some central point and group them by relevance for app, or just for "not relevant" ones do not throw exception, but return error code?

Comment: @Tigran: Imo in the temp file case you should explicitly catch the `IOException` and handle it right there. I would avoid some central exception handling facility (other than logging the exception before the crash) since I doubt that this central facility would be able to really *handle* all of these exceptions.

Comment: By "handle" I think you mean correctly behave in regard of the stack of calls + app state in that moment, which can potentially be different even in case of catching exactly same type of exception. Correct?

Comment: The method (service) processing a call (like a FileSave) should FAIL (and throw exception) if it cannot Save the file. It does not (and should not) need to know whether the client calling it needs it to succeed or not... it has to assume that any call or request it is processing is critical to the caller. The caller must make the decision as to what to do in the case of failure. it knows whether the call it is making is critical to what it is doing

Comment: In general every method should throw an excpetion if it cannot successfully complete it's one main simple purpose, whatever that is. If that purpose is to "Save a file", then if it can't save the file it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, my rule is that if an error occurs that the code I'm writing can't specifically handle, I'll throw an exception. For instance, if I'm writing a function that accepts a couple of arguments, and the function is meaningless if the arguments are `null` I'll check for that and throw some `ArgumentNullException`'s

Answer (score 3):

Generally, a method, subroutine, component, service, or system should throw an exception only when that thing *cannot do (successfully complete) whatever it was asked to do*.

"whatever it was asked to do" is somewhat subjective, of course.   As an example, if you have a method in a utility library that is named SaveFile() and it fails to save the file, but you called it from a client that is attempting to save a file to a location that might or might exist, and the client app doesn't even care if the file gets saved or not... Then the utility library SaveFile() method should still throw an exception, and the client should swallow it in the place where it was called.

Comment: Swallow might be the wrong term. Handling the exception right where it occured is what you want then.

Comment: Can't handle it where it occurred because that method should not be coded to know (or care) whether or not the client calling it needs it to succeed or not... it has to assume that any call (request) it is processing is critical to the caller.  The caller must make the decision as t owhat to do in the case of failure. it knows whether the call it is making is critical to what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that I could express the exhaustive list, but a few good examples might include

1. When you need to stop/alter
   execution for a scenario that
   wouldn't cause any system exceptions
   (if there are no foos with n bars
   the system is in trouble, throw a
   custom exception)
2. When you are at a boundary where the
       system exception would include data
       that was not needed, or possibly not
       desirable to expose (users my not
       need to see everything in the stack
       trace, but you could log the actual exception then throw a custom
       exception (Data Access, Service Access,
       etc) that allows you to control what
       is propagated downstream.
3. When you can add additional
       contextual information to an
       exception, i.e. you caught some
       exception and can use it as the
       inner exception for a new exception
       that includes information that can
       be useful for logging/debugging etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw exceptions whenever your application enters any exceptional state. There may be invariants violated ("x can never be null!" is a good invariant which may be covered by an assertion or exception). Maybe something went terribly wrong, e.g. another machine sent corrupt data. Of course everything would result in some exception or error of the runtime of your choice (java, .net), but whenever your custom exception would be more concise (closer to the line of code which caused the problem, better naming, ...) than the built-in one, it's a possible candidate for a custom exception.

Theres another reason for custom exceptions: If all of your exceptions would inherit from a custom exception class, it's easier for the client to catch the exceptions he's interested in. Most of the time nobody wants to catch NPEs or stuff like that, so it may be more convenient to catch a smaller range of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

every method has a return type (whether that type be void, int, string, car, etc.) an exception allows you to return a message to a calling context that is NOT of type T, but is of Type Exception that says "something went wrong". What went wrong is identify by the derived  type (from exception, as SQLException) and message. This creates a uniform interface (by type exception) for messaging errors.